# Inserting into map with types <int, vector<int>>

Tags: c++, vector, dictionary, insert

I have this code:

```
map< int , vector< int>> testmap;
vector<int> testvector;
testvector.push_back(10);
testmap.insert(1, testvector);
```

This code is giving me an error, telling me that there is no overloaded function to match the argument list.

Can anyone tell me why this is happening? I'm trying to insert a vector into a map but this method doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Have a look at [this documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map/insert).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no overload of `std::map::insert` matching the arguments you are passing. This would work:

```
auto p = testmap.insert(std::make_pair(1, testvector));

std::cout << std::boolalpha;
std::cout << "Did insert succeed? " << p.second << std::endl;
```

This will succeed if there is no element in the map with key `1`.

Answer (score 3):

```
testmap.insert(1, testvector);
```

You probably meant to do

```
testmap[1] = testvector;
```

instead.

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using C++11 (as evidenced by your use of `>>` :)), you can also use [`emplace`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/map/emplace/).

```
testmap.emplace(1, testvector);
```

Answer (score 0):

try

```
testmap.insert({1, testvector});
```